# GA Framework for Virtual Machines

Tags: .net, virtual-machine, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, instruction-set

Does anyone know of any .NET genetic algorithm frameworks for evolving instructions sets in virtual machines to solve abstract problems? I would be particularly interested in a framework which allows virtual machines to self propagate within a pool and evolve against a fitness function determined by a data set with "good" outputs given expected inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MicroGP](http://www.cad.polito.it/research/microgp.html) is a framework for evolving programs that is retargetable - if a CLR target does not exist, you can create one.

It has been used for making winning [corewars warriors](http://corewar.co.uk/), as well as the serious task of verifying processor implementations.

It has received sponsorship from Intel.